# Can I use my harddisk as memory when I get MemoryError in Python?

Tags: python, memory, dask

I have big dask dataframe 45 million records

that I am trying to pivot using

```
features_df = df_features.pivot_table(index='filename', columns='code', values='frequency')
```

but I get this error

```
File "C:\Users\ASMGX\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\sorting.py", line 65, in get_group_index
    labels, shape = map(list, zip(*map(maybe_lift, labels, shape)))

  File "pandas\_libs\algos_common_helper.pxi", line 361, in pandas._libs.algos.ensure_int64

MemoryError
```

Is there anyway I can use my harddisk to act as memory or a place to keep temp files?

Comment: Start with mmap?

Comment: @Prune what is mmap and how to use it?

Comment: Come on -- you've been here long enough to know better.  :-)  You find out what `mmap` is by looking it up in your browser; you learn how to use it by searching for examples.

Comment: @Prune I swear I tried what I found is that it is to create files https://docs.python.org/2/library/mmap.html and could not get how to use it when memory is full !

Comment: It is used to map memory to file space.  If this doesn't have needed virtual capabilities, then it's not useful to you.  Instead, you'll need to research using disk as virtual memory -- not in my skill set or knowledge.